# Include a template which is in the web folder

Tags: symfony, twig

I am creating a website in which I let people upload their own twig templates. These template files are stored into the web folder.

How can I include one of those files in another template.

I tried this :

```
{% include dirname(__FILE__) ~ '/../../../../web/designs/' ~ target.design.filekey ~ '/DesignKit/design.html.twig' %}
```

But I get an error telling that the dirname function does not exist.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

use:

```
{% include '@web_dir/build/templates/templates.html.min.twig' %}
```

and

```
# config.yml
twig:
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../web": web_dir
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use php syntaxes inside twig. You can create a [global variable](http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md) with the path to the web directory:

```
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        web_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../web
```

You may also able to reuse the [asset function](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets)